# Django Edit Form Queryset made of Query + Current Selected Option - How to get?

Tags: python, django, forms, django-queryset

My forms.py

```
class CreateVesselForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Vessel
    exclude = ['active']

# Filtering Choices
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CreateVesselForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Filtering just Free Slots
    self.fields['slot'].queryset = Slot.objects.filter(is_free=True)
    # Filtering just Free Storages
    self.fields['storage'].queryset = Storage.objects.filter(is_free=True)
```

The Slot Field is a ForeignKey and the Storage Field is a ManytoMany Field.

In my views.py, by the time I save this form I change the status of "is_free" to False. However when the time to edit this item(Vessel) - getting it from a form instance - the options already selected before, no longer appear in the form fields because my queryset is filtering just by status=True.

The perfect form queryset for me would be:

**for ForeignKey**

the current selected item "vessel.slot" + Slot.objects.filter(is_free=True) ?

**for ManytoMany**

the current selected item "vessel.storage" + Storage.objects.filter(is_free=True) ?

Is there a way to get it done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
class CreateVesselForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Vessel
        exclude = ['active']

    # Filtering Choices
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateVesselForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs['instance']:
            self.fields['storage'].queryset = kwargs['instance'].storage.all()|Storage.objects.filter(is_free=True)
            self.fields['slot'].queryset = Slot.objects.filter(pk=kwargs['instance'].slot.pk)|Slot.objects.filter(is_free=True)
```